# .on() from for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my current project i have multiple line like this:

```
$$(document).on('change','#x1', function () {
   console.log('fired');
});
$$(document).on('change','#x2', function () {
   console.log('fired');
});
$$(document).on('change','#x3', function () {
   console.log('fired');
});
```

is it possible to replace this with some of a for loop?
(my example isn't working)

```
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
   $$(document).on('change','#x'+i, function () {
   });
}
```

Comment: I don't see any Ajax here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need of loop use [comma separated multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

```
$$(document).on('change','#x1,#x2,#x3', function () {
   console.log('fired');
});
```

---

**FYI :**  Always it's better to use a common class to group of elements and attach event handler using class name.

---

If there are n selectors then you can generate selector using for loop.

```
var sel = '';
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
   sel += (i > 1? ',' : '') + '#x' + i;
}
```

ES6 alternatives

```
var sel = Array.from({ length:3 },(_, i) => '#x' + (i + 1)).join(',');
```

---

An another option would [attribute start with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) but it would select all element where it's `id` is start with `x`.

```
$$(document).on('change','[id^="x"]', function () {
   console.log('fired');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! it is possible to create this event also with n #x?

Comment: @t333o :  using the loop generate the selector

Comment: @t333o : an es6 method `Array.from({length:3},(
_,i) => '#x' + (i + 1)).join(',');`

Comment: @t333o : or `var sel = ''; for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) { sel += (i > 1? ',' : '') + '#x' + i; } $$(document).on('change',sel,.......`

Comment: Thanks alot. I think the es6-solution is attractive, but there are compatibility issues with old browsers like IE10, right? - so i will take the for loop solution.

Comment: @t333o : glad to help :)